# Why sometimes linking with .so files give linker errors?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I am too much curious about the issue that sometimes .so linking fails, but whenever I use static libs (.a) it doesn't. Do anyone have idea on that?

For example in linux I have used libcrypto.a lib which is ok every compilation time. But libcrypto.so is so much inconsistent. What is the root cause of that?

The error it shows is : `ld: libcrypto.so in wrong file format`

Comment: We can't guess unless you give a precise and *concrete* example. Recall that order of arguments to `gcc` (actually to the underlying `ld` linker) is important.

Comment: it says `ld: libcrypto.so in wrong file format`

Comment: Then try `file -L /usr/lib/libcrypto.so` or `file -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so` to find out what is your `libcrypto.so`; on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 I'm getting `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64`... You may want to re-install the package providing it (`libssl-dev` on my Debian)

Comment: And the `visual-c++` tag is wrong in your question.

Comment: ok thanks. I will remember the facts next time whenever I will tag a topic.

Comment: Actually sometimes it fails and sometimes it works. I have heard from a expert it is a common problem for .so files, he suggested me to use .a files instead. But I want to know the root cause of that.

Comment: Such issues never occurred to me. You really should improve your question with a real, self-contained, small, example (some C source code and the compiler command used to build it).

Comment: Your expert is wrong. The reason of the inconsistent behaviour may be broken hardware. Try running `memtest86` and whatever disk check utility your filesystem normally uses.

Comment: thanks. Is `memetest86` app;icable for any architecture of linux?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have a project, which occurs fine with .a files of openssl but fails (Sometimes) for .so files of openssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Solved it. You are right @n.m. Your comment worked for me.

> Your expert is wrong. The reason of the inconsistent behaviour may be broken hardware. Try running memtest86 and whatever disk check utility your filesystem normally uses. – n.m.

Thanks.